# WPF ObservableCollection Item's

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatrigger

I have an ObservableCollection which is binded to a ListView:

```
private ObservableCollection<Cost> m_Costs;
public ObservableCollection<Cost> DatabaseRecords 
{
    get { return m_Costs; }
}
```

and

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseRecords, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

When I add or remove item the UI will refresh, it's OK. But what if I change a property of an item in the collection? I have a DataTrigger which handle formatting items based on their property:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="Removed">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

If I change the Status property the UI doesn't refresh.

```
m_Costs[0].Status = UIStatus.Removed;
```

Any idea how can I utilize the binding to refresh?

Comment: How is your Status property defined? I think Status should then implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your ObservableCollection you don't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, cause it's already *observable*.

But for your Status property you need to implement it, otherwise your View will not know that property was changed.